# How do I choose the layout used for pagination?

Tags: jekyll

I have a newspaper website generated by Jekyll, I’d like to paginate the articles. I want to use one layout for the front page (`/`) and a different (simpler) layout for subsequent pages (`/page2` etc). But the built-in paginator picks up the front page layout and uses that to generate all subsequent pages. How can I use a different layout there, without using plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the [pagination documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/), you can use the `paginator.previous_page` variable to know if you are on the first page or not and then adapt you layout accordingly.

In `/index.html` can use this logic for presentation :

```
{% if paginator.previous_page %}
  Not on first page
  subsequent page layout here
{% else %}
  On first page
  First page layout here
{% endif %}
```